# Rails - Pagination gem showing all items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, rubygems, has-many

I am using the pagination gem to paginate customer orders. I've had to display the orders using relationships through the database:

```
<table class="order-items">
<th>Date</th>
<th>Order No.</th>
<th>View Order</th>
<% @customer.orders.each do |order| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= order.created_at.strftime("%d %b. %Y") %></td>
        <td><%= order.id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show',  "../orders/#{order.id}" %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>   
</table>

<p><%= will_paginate @orders %></p>
```

And the code in my controller:

```
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  @order = @customer.orders
  @orders = @order.paginate page: params[:page], order: 'title',
  per_page: 5
```

I've created 6 orders for this customer to test it. The problem I'm having is that the pagination pages appear correctly at the bottom (2 pages), but all 6 orders are still displayed in the list, and both paginated pages still show all 6 orders.

I've managed to get the pagination to work fine for all other pages, so I'm assuming it's because I've got the order.line_items.each construct in there - so that's why it displays all 6. I don't know how to fix this though! Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should add below line in view before each statement

```
    <%= will_paginate @orders %>
```

Comment: Sorry, before which statements? Thanks

Comment: before @order.line_items.each

Comment: I think you should use @orders.line_items.each

Comment: That's still not working - I've tried both those alterations and still no difference :S

Comment: Really sorry, wrong code in the top, will change what I've got!

Comment: Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? It's just iterating over all the orders for both pages, and not paginating them :S. Both paginated pages have all 6 orders in them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

In controller:

```
 @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
 @order_items = @customer.orders.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

In view:

```
<table class="order-items">
<th>Date</th>
<th>Order No.</th>
<th>View Order</th>

<%= will_paginate @order_items %>

<% @order_items.each do |order| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= order.created_at.strftime("%d %b. %Y") %></td>
    <td><%= order.id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show',  "../orders/#{order.id}" %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>   
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) which looks a more cleaner way of doing and implementing things

In your controller

```
@orders = Kaminari.paginate_array(Customer.find(params[:id]).orders).page(params[:page])
```

In Your model assign the per page that you want

```
paginates_per 10
```

In your view

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= order.created_at.strftime("%d %b. %Y") %></td>
    <td><%= order.id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show',  "../orders/#{order.id}" %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>

<%= paginate @orders %>
```

I hope it helps